# xs:assert with count of number of elements

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

I cannot somehow count the number of sibling elements with name "x" in an extract of this XSD schema?

```
    </xs:all>
    <xs:assert test="count(./x) = 1"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

This should count how many "x" elements I have but somehow Xerces J spits out only:
**Output:**

```
Assertion evaluation ('count(./x) = 1') for element 'Properties' with type 'FF' did not succeed.
```

What I am doing wrong? What else might be the reason for the assertion to fail? Elemen x exists in the definition and also in the XML...???? Do I need namespaces or something like this?

I can reproduce correct bahaviour in a simple test but not for my complex XSD above...:

```
<Example>

    <y/>
    <y/>
    <y/>
</Example>
```

**XSD**

```
     <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="Example" type="SS"/>

    <xs:complexType name="SS">
        <xs:all>
          <xs:element name="y" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:all>
        <xs:assert test="count(y) = 3" />
      </xs:complexType>

  </xs:schema>
```

**Found the error:**
I think, because I have a namespace "sp"  i need to provide this to XPath as well to make is work:

```
<xs:assert test="count(./sp:y) = 3" />
```

Comment: Does your schema have a targetNamespace, and if so then have you set elementFormDefault?

Comment: I would suspect namespaces as well. Show us a complete schema and instance document.

Comment: I think I found the error : see above